# How do I extend this query to find valid combinations of three items?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I totally don't expect to get any answers here, but I'll try anyway.

So this came out of playing Skyrim. I wanted an easy way to look up what ingredients can be combined to make different potions/poisons so I made an Ingredient table that has an ID and a Name; an Effect table that has an ID, Name, Poison flag, and Potion flag (potion and poison are mutually exclusive); and a join table that has ID for ingredient and ID for effect.

So the way it works is every ingredient has 4 different effects, effects are repeated on mulitple ingredients. In the game you can combine 2 or 3 ingredients and the result is a potion or poison with all of the effects that are matching on at least 2 of the ingredients used. So if you use 3 ingredients and effect1 is on both ingredient1 and ingredient2 and effect2 is on both ingredient1 and ingredient3 your result will be a potion/poison that has  both effect1 and effect2.

I was able to come up with a query on my own that will show every possible 2 ingredient combination that creates a potion with no poison effects. First I need to find every possible 2 ingredient combination that only has matching effects that are not "poison":

```
SELECT i1.UniqIngredient UniqIngredient1, i2.UniqIngredient UniqIngredient2
FROM Ingredient i1
CROSS JOIN Ingredient i2
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt1 ON i1.UniqIngredient = jt1.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt2 ON i2.UniqIngredient = jt2.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Effect e ON jt1.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect
WHERE i1.UniqIngredient < i2.UniqIngredient
GROUP BY i1.UniqIngredient, i2.UniqIngredient
HAVING SUM(e.Poison) = 0
```

Ingredient is cross joined with Ingredient to get every combination but because the order of the ingredients doesn't matter, I'd end up with double the results. That's why the WHERE checks i1.UniqIngredient < i2.UniqIngredient. I will only ever see each combination once and the lower ID of the 2 ingredients will always be in the 1st column.
I join both ingredients to the same effect, because I only care about combinations that produce a result.
Then I group them by the 2 ingredients and count up how many poison effects they share because I only want combinations that have 0 poison effects.

Then I use this result as a table that I join back to the Ingredient and Effect tables to get a list of every possible 2 ingredient combination that produces potions, and what effects each combination has:

```
SELECT i1.Name, i2.Name, e.Name
FROM (SELECT i1.UniqIngredient UniqIngredient1, i2.UniqIngredient UniqIngredient2
FROM Ingredient i1
CROSS JOIN Ingredient i2
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt1 ON i1.UniqIngredient = jt1.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt2 ON i2.UniqIngredient = jt2.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Effect e ON jt1.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect
WHERE i1.UniqIngredient < i2.UniqIngredient
GROUP BY i1.UniqIngredient, i2.UniqIngredient
HAVING SUM(e.Poison) = 0) il
INNER JOIN Ingredient i1 ON il.UniqIngredient1 = i1.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Ingredient i2 ON il.UniqIngredient2 = i2.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt1 ON i1.UniqIngredient = jt1.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt2 ON i2.UniqIngredient = jt2.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Effect e ON jt1.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect
ORDER BY i1.Name, i2.Name, e.Name
```

Using the same query I can find 2 ingredient poison combinations that have no potion effects just by changing the HAVING line to check e.Potion instead of e.Poison.

This is all fine and good, but when I want to introduce the 3rd ingredient that's where it gets tricky. I'm stumped. I can modify this query to check for 3 ingredients that all have the same effect, but that's not what I want. I want to find a 3rd ingredient that has a different effect in common with 1 of the ingredients.

Any help?

---

**EDIT**

---

Update: So after struggling with this for hours I have come up with a big, ugly, slow, hard to follow query (I actually don't even remember why I had to do that crazy join condition on the Effect table. But when I change it the whole query is 2x slower so it's actually faster the way I have it, though I don't know why...), that *almost* does what I want. This might just be as close as I can get, unless someone has any other ideas or sees a way to improve my new query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT il.Name1, il.Name2, il.Name3, e.Name
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT i1.UniqIngredient Ingredient1, i1.Name Name1, i2.UniqIngredient Ingredient2, i2.Name Name2, i3.UniqIngredient Ingredient3, i3.Name Name3
FROM Ingredient i1
INNER JOIN Ingredient i2 ON i1.UniqIngredient < i2.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Ingredient i3 ON i2.UniqIngredient < i3.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt1 ON i1.UniqIngredient = jt1.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt2 ON i2.UniqIngredient = jt2.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt3 ON i3.UniqIngredient = jt3.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Effect e ON (jt1.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND (jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect OR jt3.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect)) OR (jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND jt3.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect)
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM IngredientEffectJT jt1
               INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt2 ON jt1.UniqEffect = jt2.UniqEffect
               WHERE jt1.UniqIngredient = i1.UniqIngredient 
               AND jt2.UniqIngredient = i2.UniqIngredient)
       AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM IngredientEffectJT jt1
                    INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt3 ON jt1.UniqEffect = jt3.UniqEffect
                    WHERE jt1.UniqIngredient = i1.UniqIngredient 
                    AND jt3.UniqIngredient = i3.UniqIngredient)
         OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM IngredientEffectJT jt2
                    INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt3 ON jt2.UniqEffect = jt3.UniqEffect
                    WHERE jt2.UniqIngredient = i2.UniqIngredient 
                    AND jt3.UniqIngredient = i3.UniqIngredient)))
       OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM IngredientEffectJT jt1
                  INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt3 ON jt1.UniqEffect = jt3.UniqEffect
                  WHERE jt1.UniqIngredient = i1.UniqIngredient 
                  AND jt3.UniqIngredient = i3.UniqIngredient)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM IngredientEffectJT jt2
                  INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt3 ON jt2.UniqEffect = jt3.UniqEffect
                  WHERE jt2.UniqIngredient = i2.UniqIngredient 
                  AND jt3.UniqIngredient = i3.UniqIngredient))
GROUP BY i1.UniqIngredient, i1.Name, i2.UniqIngredient, i2.Name, i3.UniqIngredient, i3.Name
HAVING SUM(e.Poison) = 0) il
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt1 ON il.Ingredient1 = jt1.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt2 ON il.Ingredient2 = jt2.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt3 ON il.Ingredient3 = jt3.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Effect e ON (jt1.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND (jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect OR jt3.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect)) OR (jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND jt3.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect)
ORDER BY il.Name1, il.Name2, il.Name3, e.Name
```

In the inner query:

```
FROM Ingredient i1
INNER JOIN Ingredient i2 ON i1.UniqIngredient < i2.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Ingredient i3 ON i2.UniqIngredient < i3.UniqIngredient
```

This creates every possible combination of 3 ingredients where order does not matter and nothing is repeated. Then the Joins to IngredientEffectJT and Effect... I actually don't remember what the crazy join on Effect is for. Looking at it, I thought it was to ensure an effect exists on at least 2 ingredients, but that's what the WHERE clause is doing. And simplifying that Effect join causes it to run significantly slower so...whatever.

Then the GROUP BY is there so I can count the number of matching poison effects. Since I had to group by the 3 ingredients, I lose the individual matching effects so then I need to rejoin all of those ingredients back to their effects and find the effects that match.

The problem with this query is that it will show combinations where all 3 ingredients have the same 1 effect. Those combinations are pointless because you can make the same thing by only using 2 of those 3 so it's kind of wasteful.

So, this is the best I could come up with. It's really slow so maybe I'll just save it to a new table to make it easier and faster to query again in the future.

Comment: Can you provide any sample data?

Comment: Cool challenge, I will try it and come back to you.

Comment: I uploaded a script to google docs: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-weZDL1EWWuMDNlODg4MjQtM2JhNy00NDY3LTlmNGQtOTM3YjU5NWVkOWMw

This script should create and populate the tables for you. I don't know if it's all standard SQL that will run in all databases, it definitely works for microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Martin Smith's solution does not entirely solve this problem, it did inspire me to look into using CTEs and I think I got it.

Once I realized every 3 ingredient combination is really 2 different 2 ingredient combinations that share 1 common ingredient, I decided to find all 2 ingredient combinations and then find every combination of those that have at least 1 ingredient in common and both have effects that the other does not have.

Then check to make sure every 3 ingredient combination has no poison effects (I already know each individual 2 ingredient combination has no poison effects, but just because A+B has no poison and B+C has no poison doesn't mean A+B+C won't have poison. It's possible that combing A with C will produce a poison effect).

Then I join all 3 ingredients back to the Effect table to display which effects are produced with each combination.

This query has a 3 minute 50 second execution time on my system. That's not cool. But at least I am getting the results I want now.

```
WITH Combination AS
(
    --Finds all 2 ingredient combinations that have shared effects that are not poisons
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i1.Name, i2.Name) UniqCombination, i1.UniqIngredient UniqIngredient1, i2.UniqIngredient UniqIngredient2, COUNT(1) NumberOfEffects
    from Ingredient i1
    cross join Ingredient i2
    INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt1 ON i1.UniqIngredient = jt1.UniqIngredient
    INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt2 ON i2.UniqIngredient = jt2.UniqIngredient
    INNER JOIN Effect e ON jt1.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect
    WHERE i1.UniqIngredient < i2.UniqIngredient
    GROUP BY i1.UniqIngredient, i1.name, i2.UniqIngredient, i2.Name
    HAVING SUM(e.poison) = 0
),
Potion AS
(
    --Matches up all 2 ingredient combinations in the Combination CTE with the effects for that combination
    SELECT DISTINCT c.UniqCombination, c.UniqIngredient1, i1.Name Ingredient1, c.UniqIngredient2, i2.Name Ingredient2, e.UniqEffect, e.Name Effect
    FROM Combination c
    INNER JOIN Ingredient i1 ON c.UniqIngredient1 = i1.UniqIngredient
    INNER JOIN Ingredient i2 ON c.UniqIngredient2 = i2.UniqIngredient
    INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt1 ON c.UniqIngredient1 = jt1.UniqIngredient
    INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt2 ON c.UniqIngredient2 = jt2.UniqIngredient
    INNER JOIN Effect e ON jt1.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect

),
BigCombination AS
(
    --Matches 2 combinations together where 1 ingredient is the same in both combinations.
    SELECT c1.UniqIngredient1, CASE WHEN c1.UniqIngredient1 = c2.UniqIngredient1 THEN c1.UniqIngredient2 ELSE c2.UniqIngredient1 END UniqIngredient2, c2.UniqIngredient2 UniqIngredient3
    FROM Combination c1
    INNER JOIN Combination c2 ON (c1.UniqIngredient1 = c2.UniqIngredient1 OR c1.UniqIngredient2 = c2.UniqIngredient1 OR c1.UniqIngredient2 = c2.UniqIngredient2) AND c1.UniqCombination < c2.UniqCombination
    --This WHERE clause sucks because there are 2 different select queries that must run twice each.
    --They have to run twice because I have to EXCEPT 1 from 2 and 2 from 1 to make sure both combinations are contributing something new.
    WHERE EXISTS( SELECT p1.UniqEffect
                  FROM Potion p1
                  WHERE p1.UniqCombination = c1.UniqCombination
                  EXCEPT
                  SELECT p2.UniqEffect
                  FROM Potion p2
                  WHERE p2.UniqCombination = c2.UniqCombination)
    AND EXISTS( SELECT p2.UniqEffect
                FROM Potion p2
                WHERE p2.UniqCombination = c2.UniqCombination
                EXCEPT
                SELECT p1.UniqEffect
                FROM Potion p1
                WHERE p1.UniqCombination = c1.UniqCombination)
),
BigPotionCombination AS
(
    --Combinations were made only from other combinations that made potions, but it's possible the new
    --ingredients mixing together could create a new poison effect. This will remove combinations that create new poison effects
    SELECT DISTINCT c.*
    FROM BigCombination c
    INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt1 ON c.UniqIngredient1 = jt1.UniqIngredient
    INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt2 ON c.UniqIngredient2 = jt2.UniqIngredient
    INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt3 ON c.UniqIngredient3 = jt3.UniqIngredient
    INNER JOIN Effect e ON (jt1.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND (jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect OR jt3.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect)) OR (jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND jt3.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect)
    GROUP BY c.UniqIngredient1, c.UniqIngredient2, c.UniqIngredient3
    HAVING SUM(e.Poison) = 0
)

--Combinations have to be joined back to Effect again to display the effects that the potions have.
SELECT DISTINCT i1.Name Ingredient1, i2.Name Ingredient2, i3.Name Ingredient3, e.Name Effect
FROM BigPotionCombination c
INNER JOIN Ingredient i1 ON c.UniqIngredient1 = i1.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Ingredient i2 ON c.UniqIngredient2 = i2.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Ingredient i3 ON c.UniqIngredient3 = i3.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt1 ON c.UniqIngredient1 = jt1.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt2 ON c.UniqIngredient2 = jt2.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN IngredientEffectJT jt3 ON c.UniqIngredient3 = jt3.UniqIngredient
INNER JOIN Effect e ON (jt1.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND (jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect OR jt3.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect)) OR (jt2.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect AND jt3.UniqEffect = e.UniqEffect)
ORDER BY Ingredient1, Ingredient2, Ingredient3, Effect
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
declare @combos table (comboId int identity, ingredient1 int, ingredient2 int, ingredient3 int null)

--create table of all unique 2 and 3 ingredient combinations (unique potions)
insert int @combos (ingredient1, ingredient2, ingredient3)
select 
    distinct
    i1.ID,
    i2.ID,
    i3.ID
from
    ingredient i1
    inner join ingredient i2 on i1.ID < i2.ID
    left outer join ingredient i3 on i2.ID < i3.ID

--create table to hold mapping between unique combinations and ingredients
declare @combo_ingredient table (ComboId int, IngredientId int)

--insert into the mapping table
insert into @combo_ingredient (ComboId, IngredientId)
select ID, ingredient1 from @combos

insert into @combo_ingredient (ComboId, IngredientId)
select ID, ingredient1 from @combos

insert into @combo_ingredient (ComboId, IngredientId)
select ID, ingredient3 from @combos where ingredient3 is not null

--create table to hold mapping between unique combinations (potions) and the effects it will have
declare @combo_effect (comboId int, effectId int)

insert into @combo_effect (comboId, effectId)
select 
    c.ComboId, ec.EffectId
from
    @combo_ingredient c
    inner join effect_ingredient ec on c.IngredientId = ec.IngredientId
having
    count(*) > 1
group by 
    c.comboId, ec.EffectId

--remove combinations that include an ingredient that do not contribute to an effect
delete from @combo_effect ce
where ce.ComboId in (
    select 
        ci.ComboId 
    from 
        @combo_ingredient ci
        inner join effect_ingredient ei on ci.IngredientId = ei.IngredientId
        left outer join @combo_effect ce on ce.ComboId = ci.ComboId and ce.EffectId = ei.EffectId
    where 
        ce.ComboId is null
)

--you can then query combo_effect for whatever information you want
--all combos with no poison effects
select comboId from 
    @combo_effect ce 
    left outer join effect e on ce.effectId = e.effectId and e.PoisonFlag = 1
group by 
    comboId
having 
    Count(e.id) = 0
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is it shows all combinations that produce an effect even if one of the ingredients in that combination isn't needed. For example when i ran ran that the first combo it found had 3 ingredients, the 1st ingredient does not have anything in common with the 2nd or 3rd ingredient. it shows as a combo because #2 and 3 have something in common. I do not want combinations like this to show up.

Comment: Ahh, OK. You want only combinations where all ingredients contribute to an effect. I can edit it to remove those combinations. What about combinations that contain an ingredient that contributes to the same, and only, effect as the first two ingredients?

Comment: Yes, I only want combinations where every ingredient is contributing an effect. In the case where all 3 ingredients provide the same effect, I do not want those. Unless they do provide a new effect as well.

Comment: I put a link to a script that will create and populate the tables in a comment under the original post, it might help to actually be able to look at the data.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how this will perform, but it's a lot simpler I think:

```
select
          (select Name from Ingredient where ID = e1.UniqIngredient) as Ingredient1,
          (select Name from Ingredient where ID = jt1.UniqIngredient) as Ingredient2,
          (select Name from Ingredient where ID = jt2.UniqIngredient) as Ingredient3,
          ee1.Name as Effect1,
          ee2.Name as Effect2
   from IngredientEffectJT e1
       inner join IngredientEffectJT e2 on e1.UniqEffect < e2.UniqEffect and e1.UniqIngredient = e2.UniqIngredient
       inner join IngredientEffectJT jt1 on jt1.UniqEffect = e1.UniqEffect and e1.UniqIngredient != jt1.UniqIngredient
   inner join IngredientEffectJT jt2 on jt2.UniqEffect = e2.UniqEffect and e1.UniqIngredient != jt2.UniqIngredient and jt1.UniqIngredient != jt2.UniqIngredient
       inner join Effect ee1 on e1.UniqEffect = ee1.ID
       inner join Effect ee2 on e2.UniqEffect = ee2.ID
   where ee1.Poison = ee2.Poison
;
```

EDIT: Forgot Poison check.

EDIT: try2: (edited again to handle any ingredient as shared, not just lowest ID)

```
select
  (select Name from Ingredient where ID = i1) as Ingredient1,
  (select Name from Ingredient where ID = i2) as Ingredient2,
  (select Name from Ingredient where ID = i3) as Ingredient3,
  min(Poison) as Poison
  -- , group_concat(Name) as Effects
  from
(
select
      a.*,
      min(e.Name) as Name,
      min(e.Poison) as Poison
   from
(
   select -- straight_join
          i1.ID as i1,
          i2.ID as i2,
          i3.ID as i3
   from IngredientEffectJT e1
       inner join IngredientEffectJT e2 on e1.UniqEffect < e2.UniqEffect and e1.UniqIngredient = e2.UniqIngredient
       inner join Effect ee1 on e1.UniqEffect = ee1.ID
       inner join Effect ee2 on e2.UniqEffect = ee2.ID and ee1.Poison = ee2.Poison
       inner join IngredientEffectJT jt1 on jt1.UniqEffect = e1.UniqEffect and e1.UniqIngredient != jt1.UniqIngredient
       inner join IngredientEffectJT jt2 on jt2.UniqEffect = e2.UniqEffect and jt1.UniqIngredient != jt2.UniqIngredient and e1.UniqIngredient != jt2.UniqIngredient
       inner join Ingredient i1
         on (i1.ID = e1.UniqIngredient  and e1.UniqIngredient < jt1.UniqIngredient and e1.UniqIngredient < jt2.UniqIngredient)
         or (i1.ID = jt1.UniqIngredient and jt1.UniqIngredient < e1.UniqIngredient and jt1.UniqIngredient < jt2.UniqIngredient)
         or (i1.ID = jt2.UniqIngredient and jt2.UniqIngredient < jt1.UniqIngredient and jt2.UniqIngredient < e1.UniqIngredient)
       inner join Ingredient i3
         on (i3.ID = e1.UniqIngredient  and e1.UniqIngredient > jt1.UniqIngredient and e1.UniqIngredient > jt2.UniqIngredient)
         or (i3.ID = jt1.UniqIngredient and jt1.UniqIngredient > e1.UniqIngredient and jt1.UniqIngredient > jt2.UniqIngredient)
         or (i3.ID = jt2.UniqIngredient and jt2.UniqIngredient > jt1.UniqIngredient and jt2.UniqIngredient > e1.UniqIngredient)
       inner join Ingredient i2 on i2.ID = e1.UniqIngredient + jt1.UniqIngredient + jt2.UniqIngredient - i1.ID - i3.ID
     group by i1.ID, i2.ID, i3.ID
) as a
inner join IngredientEffectJT as jt on a.i1 = jt.UniqIngredient or a.i2 = jt.UniqIngredient or a.i3 = jt.UniqIngredient
inner join Effect e on jt.UniqEffect = e.ID
group by i1, i2, i3, e.ID
having count(*) >= 2
) as b
group by b.i1, b.i2, b.i3
having sum(Poison) = count(*) or sum(Poison) = 0
-- order by count(distinct Name) desc
 order by i1, i2, i3
;
```

EDIT3:

For SQL Server replace group_concat() line with:

```
  ,(
    (
    select min(e.Name) + ',' as [data()] from IngredientEffectJT jt
       inner join Effect e on jt.UniqEffect = e.ID
       where i1=jt.UniqIngredient or i2=jt.UniqIngredient or i3=jt.UniqIngredient
       group by jt.UniqEffect
       having COUNT(*) >= 2
       for xml path('')
    )
  ) as Effects
```

Comment: Yours shows columns for Effect1 and Effect2, but a 3 ingredient combination can have as many as 6 effects. Ingredient1 can have effects A, B, C, and D; Ingredient2 can have effects A, B, E, F; Ingredient3 can have effects C, D, E, F. The result would have effects A, B, C, D, E, and F.

Comment: @user862495 Modified to show all effects and remove duplicate ingredient sets.  (runs in about 1 second on my system).  p.s. - The most effects I see in one transmute is 4.  (I tested with 6 but had to change the data)

Comment: Your query is not returning the correct results. i changed the order by to b.i1, b.i2, b.i3 so I could compare your results to mine and the 1st row in my results is 'Abecean Longfin' + 'Bear Claws' + 'Hawk Feathers'. This combination does not exist in your results.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one go at it.

```
;WITH IngredientCombinations AS
(
SELECT i1.UniqIngredient AS i1_UniqIngredient,
       i1.Name AS i1_Name,
       i2.UniqIngredient AS i2_UniqIngredient,
       i2.Name AS i2_Name,
       i3.UniqIngredient AS i3_UniqIngredient,
       i3.Name AS i3_Name,
       i1.UniqIngredient AS i1_UniqIngredientB,
       i2.UniqIngredient AS i2_UniqIngredientB,
       i3.UniqIngredient AS i3_UniqIngredientB       
FROM   Ingredient i1
       JOIN Ingredient i2
         ON i1.UniqIngredient < i2.UniqIngredient
       JOIN Ingredient i3
         ON i2.UniqIngredient < i3.UniqIngredient 
)
, UnpivotedIngredientCombinations AS
(
SELECT i1_UniqIngredient,
       i1_Name,
       i2_UniqIngredient,
       i2_Name,
       i3_UniqIngredient,
       i3_Name,
       UniqIngredient
FROM IngredientCombinations
UNPIVOT
   (UniqIngredient FOR idx IN 
      (i1_UniqIngredientB, i2_UniqIngredientB, i3_UniqIngredientB)
)AS unpvt),
Effects AS
(
SELECT uic.i1_Name,
       uic.i1_UniqIngredient,
       uic.i2_Name,
       uic.i2_UniqIngredient,
       uic.i3_Name,
       uic.i3_UniqIngredient,
       uic.UniqIngredient,
       e.Name,
       e.Poison,
       e.Potion,
       e.UniqEffect,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY i1_UniqIngredient, 
                                   i2_UniqIngredient,
                                   i3_UniqIngredient, 
                                   e.UniqEffect) AS Cnt
FROM   UnpivotedIngredientCombinations uic
       JOIN IngredientEffectJT iej
         ON iej.UniqIngredient = uic.UniqIngredient
       JOIN Effect e
         ON e.UniqEffect = iej.UniqEffect  
)
SELECT i1_Name,
       i2_Name,
       i3_Name
FROM   Effects
GROUP  BY i1_UniqIngredient,
          i2_UniqIngredient,
          i3_UniqIngredient,
          i1_Name,
          i2_Name,
          i3_Name
HAVING MAX(CASE
             WHEN Cnt = 2
                  AND Poison = 1 THEN 1
           END) IS NULL
```

Comment: This gives combinations where not all 3 ingredients are contributing effects. I don't know if you ran the script i uploaded but if you did and have the populated tables you can see your query returns the combination of Abecean Longfin + Bear Claws + Bee even though Abecean Longfin has nothing in common with Bear Claws or Bee. it just shows as a combination that provides a result because Bear Claws and Bee have something in common.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here's my shot at it.

It is based on these requirements:

- Potions only, no poison effect allowed
- Two or three ingredients
- No duplicates (1-2-3, 3-2-1 are the same)
- All ingredients must be contributing to an effect
- Ingredients that are trippling an effect must be excluded unless the provide another effect

I hope the table and field names are ok, I started with my own tables but with your data.

```
select ing1.name, ing2.name, coalesce(ing3.name, ' ') from
(
-- Gives all unique combinations of two or three ingredients
    select ing1.UniqIngredient as id1, ing2.UniqIngredient as id2, 0 as id3
    from Ingredient as ing1
    inner join Ingredient as ing2 on ing1.UniqIngredient < ing2.UniqIngredient
    UNION
    select ing1.UniqIngredient as id1, ing2.UniqIngredient as id2, ing3.UniqIngredient as id3
    from Ingredient as ing1
    inner join Ingredient as ing2 on ing1.UniqIngredient < ing2.UniqIngredient
    inner join Ingredient as ing3 on ing2.UniqIngredient < ing3.UniqIngredient
) as MainRequest
join Ingredient as ing1 on ing1.UniqIngredient = id1
join Ingredient as ing2 on ing2.UniqIngredient = id2
left outer join Ingredient as ing3 on ing3.UniqIngredient = id3
where
(   -- Check if ingredients have common positive effects that are not covered by 3 ingredients (when a 3rd ingredient is present)
    exists(
    select eff.UniqEffect, count(*)
    from /Effect eff
    join IngredientEffectJT link on link.UniqEffect = eff.UniqEffect
    where eff.potion = 1 and link.UniqIngredient in (id1, id2, id3)
    group by eff.UniqEffect
    having count(*) = 2)
    AND
    not exists(
    select eff.UniqEffect, count(*)
    from Effect eff
    join IngredientEffectJT link on link.UniqEffect = eff.UniqEffect
    where eff.potion = 1 and link.UniqIngredient in (id1, id2, id3)
    group by eff.UniqEffect
    having count(*) > 2
    )
)
-- Check if ingredients have no common negative effects
AND not exists(
    select eff.UniqEffect, count(*)
    from Effect eff
    join IngredientEffectJT link on link.UniqEffect = eff.UniqEffect
    where eff.poison = 1 and link.UniqIngredient in (id1, id2, id3)
    group by eff.UniqEffect
    having count(*) >= 2)
-- Check if every ingredient is participating (No alchemist likes a freerider)
AND exists(select link1.UniqIngredient
    from IngredientEffectJT link1
    inner join IngredientEffectJT link2 on link1.UniqEffect = link2.UniqEffect
    where link1.UniqIngredient = id1 and link2.UniqIngredient in (id2, id3))
AND exists(select link1.UniqIngredient
    from IngredientEffectJT link1
    inner join IngredientEffectJT link2 on link1.UniqEffect = link2.UniqEffect
    where link1.UniqIngredient = id2 and link2.UniqIngredient in (id1, id3))
AND (id3 = 0 or
    exists(select link1.UniqIngredient
    from IngredientEffectJT link1
    inner join IngredientEffectJT link2 on link1.UniqEffect = link2.UniqEffect
    where link1.UniqIngredient = id3 and link2.UniqIngredient in (id1, id2)))
```

Comment: I'm seeing Abecean Longfin + Beehive Husk + Blisterwort in the results using your query, but Blisterwort has no effects in common with either of those other 2.

Also, Briar Heart + Red Mountain Flower + Tundra Cotton do not appear in your results, I think it is being filtered out because all 3 have Fortify Magicka, but it shouldn't be filtered out because 'Briar Heart' + 'Red Mountain Flower' add 'Restore Magicka' and 'Briar Heart' + 'Tundra Cotton' add 'Fortify Block'

 I'll post the new query I came up with here, it seems to be working exactly as i hoped, but it's still pretty slow.

Comment: Hmmm you're right. I will try to find some time to update my query to cover this. This will optimize my potion/poison making in Skyrim too :)

Answer (score -1):

This one works pretty well. http://rp.eliteskills.com/skyrim.html

Comment: That's not what I want though. I don't want to specify an ingredient and see what it can be used with. I want to see all the different combinations. doing it in my own local DB i can even enter the amount of each ingredient i have and filter the result of the query to show every possible combination of the ingredients I have.

Comment: It does generate all permutations. Click "Add all" and set the limit to 16000. It will show you all possible permutations with no repeats. This one gives worth so shows most expensive first. It's kinda tedious to enter in all ingredient amounts and make brute forcer. In general you can easily make loads of money grinding the top recipes. This one is good for filtering out potions with a particular set of desired effect.

Comment: That's still not what I want. I only want to see things I can make with the ingredients I have. My database knows my ingredients.